# Prove: for differential $y:[a,b] \to R^2$ , $y'(c)=K(y(b)-y(a))$

Tags: calculus

For $y:[a,b] \to R^2$ so $y'$ exist and $y'(t) ≠ 0$  for any $t \in  [a,b].$

Prove that there is $c \in [a,b]$ so $y'(c)=K(y(b)-y(a))$ for some $K \in \mathbb{R}.$

I tried using Lagrange mean value for each part of $y$ but its don't mean its for the same point in $[a,b].$

Edit: so i tried another solution, we know that y' exist and y is a path so we know that y is continuous so i developed Taylor to n=0 with Lagrange partial sum, so there $c \in [a,b]$ so
$y(t)=y(a)+y'(c)(x-a)$
from positioning $t=b$ we will get $y(b)-y(a)=y'(c)(b-a)$
i would be happy to know if that prove is right

Comment: Use `\to` or `\rightarrow` to get an arrow: $\to$.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

Comment: i did checked the Mean value theorem but all that i find was for functions from $R$ $\to$ $R$ and for $R^n$ $\to$ $R$